# Block Chain API for BTC transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain, api, blockchain.info

I want to fetch transactions for an address from the following api:

https://blockchain.info/address/$btc_address?format=json

The thing is understanding the json returned from the api, I don't understand which of them are the transaction and the time when that transaction took place and the confirmations of a transaction.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

The result returned from that API is a compound JSON object containing:

1. Address basic information and summary
2. List of transactions associated with that address

The transactions are included in a JSON-encoded list under the `txs` key. Every transaction itself is a dictionary-like object holding pertinent information.

It should be pretty clear when you visualize it into a tree structure. You can use **JSONView** plugin [for Firefox](http://jsonview.com/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) - it'll render all `application/json` responses in a nice hierarchical and clickable tree and help you understand it.

Comment: yea i can understand that.. im displaying in json tree structure too.. what is the exact index name for the transaction value , confirmations, time?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the transaction protocol specification. [Here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx) is the link from the bitcoin wiki.

You can map JSON keys returned from blockchain.info to the transaction protocol below. For instance the description field `version` on the wiki maps to blockchain.info's `ver`.

You need to parse through that structure according to the protocol into native structures/objects in whatever programming language you are using.